# How to make editorial table from sections

Tags: tables, sectioning, loops, foreach

How would it be possible to make an editorial list/table?

I'm not asking how to create a list or table, but if it is possible to attach something to `\section`'s and `\subsection`'s in the form of a `\label` or the like, to be able to generate the following:

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+---------+
| Section   | Subsection  | Responsible | Helpers |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+---------+
| Section 1 |             | Bob         |         |
| Section 2 |             |             |         |
|           | Section 2.1 | Jimmy       |         |
|           | Section 2.2 | Carl        |         |
| Section 3 |             | Bob         | Carl    |
|           | Section 3.1 | Jimmy       | Bob     |
| Section 4 |             | Everybody   |         |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+---------+
```

So basically is it possible to use something `\foreach` `\section` and `\subsection` to generate a table like the above. Followed by having added the information along with the sections.

Crude examples:

```
\section{Section 1}{Bob}{}
\section{Section 2}{}{}
\section{Section 3}{Bob}{Carl}
\subsection{Section 3.1}{Jimmy}{Bob}
```

Also is this a bad approach to the problem, if so is there a better one?

Comment: this is possible with [etoc package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc)

Comment: @touhami would love an example of how to use it.

Comment: @Vallentin will try. May be one can do this easily without any package. Where the table will be displayed in the begin of document or in the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*\editorialtable{%
\beforeeditorialtable
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{Section} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{Subsection} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{Responsible}&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Helpers}\\
\hline
\makeeditorialtable
\end{tabular}
\aftereditorialtable}

\newcommand*\beforeeditorialtable{\par}
\newcommand*\aftereditorialtable{\par}
\newcommand*\makeeditorialtable{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mtsection}[3]{%
\section{#1}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\g@addto@macro\protect\makeeditorialtable{#1&&#2&#3\\\protect\hline}}}
\newcommand{\mtsubsection}[3]{%
\subsection{#1}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\g@addto@macro\protect\makeeditorialtable{&#1&#2&#3\\\protect\hline}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents %  necessary 
\editorialtable
\mtsection{Section 1}{Bob}{}
\mtsection{Section 2}{}{}
\mtsection{Section 3}{Bob}{Carl}
\mtsubsection{Section 3.1}{Jimmy}{Bob}
\editorialtable
\end{document}
```

Comment: This at least works, but isn't as fancy (not that that's a bad thing).

Comment: this is just a tabular you can make it fancy (may be this is a new question)

Comment: My point was just in relation to the other answer. Nothing bad! :)

Comment: @Vallentin: You could have sent the document to me and I could have make it working, but now you've made the decision. (+1 for touhami anyway)

Answer (score 2):

See the updated and better version at the end, please!

A preliminary version with `expl3` features and key-value interface, only working for a table at the end at the moment!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{xkeyval}

\makeatletter
\let\latex@@section\section
\let\latex@@subsection\subsection


\define@key{editorial}{helper}{%
  \def\kveditorial@helper{#1}%
}

\define@key{editorial}{responsible}{%
  \def\kveditorial@responsible{#1}
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_vallentin_editorial_seq


\NewDocumentCommand{\EditorialBoard}{}{%
   \begin{tabular}{*{4}{p{3cm}}}
     \bfseries Section & \bfseries subsection & \bfseries Responsible & \bfseries Helper \tabularnewline
     \hline
     \seq_use:Nn \g_vallentin_editorial_seq {\tabularnewline}
  \end{tabular}
}



\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{somo}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \latex@@section*{#3}%
  }{%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
      \latex@@section[#2]{#3}%
    }{%
      \latex@@section{#3}%
    }%
    \IfValueTF{#4}{%
      \typeout{Some value:#4}
      \setkeys{editorial}{#4}%
      \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_vallentin_editorial_seq {#3\space\thesection & & \kveditorial@responsible  & \kveditorial@helper}%
    }{%
      \typeout{No value:#4}
      \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_vallentin_editorial_seq {#3}
    }
  }%
}


\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsection}{somo}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \latex@@subsection*{#3}%
  }{%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
      \latex@@subsection[#2]{#3}%
    }{%
      \latex@@subsection{#3}%
    }%
    \IfValueTF{#4}{%
      \setkeys{editorial}{#4}%
      \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_vallentin_editorial_seq {& #3\space\thesubsection & \kveditorial@responsible  & \kveditorial@helper}%
    }{%
      \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_vallentin_editorial_seq {& #3}
    }
  }%
}


\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Foo}[helper=Harpo,responsible=Chico]

\section{Foo bar}[helper=Gummo,responsible=Groucho]

\section{Other foo bar}

\subsection{Some subsection}[helper={some blokes from TeX.SX},responsible=You!]


\EditorialBoard


\end{document}
```

**Update**

This version allows to place `EditorialBoard` anywhere in the document body. The content is always stored at the end of the document and read at time of `\EditorialBoard` usage.

The filename is called `\jobname.edo`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xkeyval}

\makeatletter
\let\latex@@section\section
\let\latex@@subsection\subsection

% Define two keys

\define@key{editorial}{helper}{%
  \def\kveditorial@helper{#1}%
}

\define@key{editorial}{responsible}{%
  \def\kveditorial@responsible{#1}
}

\newcommand{\editorialboardname}{Editorial Board}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_vallentin_editorial_seq % Holding the content

\iow_new:N \g_vallentin_editorial_outfile
\ior_new:N \g_vallentin_editorial_infile


\cs_new:Nn \vallentin_store_editorial_content:n {%
  \iow_open:Nn \g_vallentin_editorial_outfile {#1}
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_vallentin_editorial_seq {%
    \iow_now:Nn \g_vallentin_editorial_outfile {##1}
  }
  \iow_close:N \g_vallentin_editorial_outfile % Close the file
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\StoreEditorialContent}{m}{%
  \vallentin_store_editorial_content:n{#1}
}



\cs_new:Nn \read_from_external_file:n{%
  % Only add the content if it's not already there!
  \seq_if_in:NnF \g_vallentin_editorial_seq {#1}{%
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_vallentin_editorial_seq {#1}
  }
}

\cs_new:Nn \grab_old_editorial_file:n{%
  \seq_gclear:N \g_vallentin_editorial_seq
  \ior_open:Nn \g_vallentin_editorial_infile {#1}
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \g_vallentin_editorial_infile {\read_from_external_file:n{##1}}%
  \ior_close:N \g_vallentin_editorial_infile
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\ReadEditorialContent}{m}{%
  \IfFileExists{#1}{%
    \section*{\editorialboardname}
    \grab_old_editorial_file:n {#1}
  }{}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\displayeditorialline}{}{%
  \seq_use:Nn \g_vallentin_editorial_seq {\tabularnewline\midrule} % Display all in a row!
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\AddSectionEditorialLine}{m}{%
  \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_vallentin_editorial_seq {#1}
}


\ExplSyntaxOff

% Redefine the section commands -- does not work for memoir.cls!
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{somo}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \latex@@section*{#3}%
  }{%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
      \latex@@section[#2]{#3}%
    }{%
      \latex@@section{#3}%
    }%
    \IfValueTF{#4}{%
      \setkeys{editorial}{#4}%
      \AddSectionEditorialLine{#3 \thesection & & \kveditorial@responsible  & \kveditorial@helper}%
    }{%
      \AddSectionEditorialLine{#3}
    }
  }%
}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsection}{somo}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \latex@@subsection*{#3}%
  }{%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
      \latex@@subsection[#2]{#3}%
    }{%
      \latex@@subsection{#3}%
    }%
    \IfValueTF{#4}{%
      \setkeys{editorial}{#4}%
      \AddSectionEditorialLine{& #3 \thesubsection & \kveditorial@responsible  & \kveditorial@helper}%
    }{%
      \AddSectionEditorialLine{& #3}%
    }%
  }%
}



\makeatother


\AtEndDocument{%
  \StoreEditorialContent{\jobname.edo}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\EditorialBoard}{O{\jobname.edo}}{%
  \clearpage
  \ReadEditorialContent{#1}%
  \begin{tabular}{*{4}{p{3cm}}}
    \bfseries Section & \bfseries Subsection & \bfseries Responsible & \bfseries Helper \tabularnewline
    \toprule
    \displayeditorialline%
  \end{tabular}
}




\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\EditorialBoard


\section{Foo}[helper=Harpo,responsible=Chico]

\section{Foo bar}[helper=Gummo,responsible=Groucho]

\section{Other foo bar}

\subsection{Some subsection}[helper={some blokes from TeX.SX},responsible=You!]

\subsection{Other stuff}[helper={Ann Elk},responsible={Arthur Gumby}]

\section{A new section}[responsible={Gandalf},helper={Frodo}]



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't get neither of those to work. The second (update) won't even compile. The first compiles, but only shows sections which doesn't have the `[helper=...]` stuff after. It also only shows stuff in the "Section" part, but nothing more than that.

Comment: @Vallentin: You seem to have a faulty or outdated TeX installation then -- as you can see from the screen shot, it works. I am using Linux, TL 2015

Comment: I'm using sharelatex.com, and honestly don't know that much of the inner workings of LaTeX! :)

Comment: @Vallentin: Sharelatex, oh my ... well, I know why I don't like this kind of stuff.

Comment: I'm using it, as we're multiple people working on the same document.

Comment: @Vallentin: Look here: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/5747502e479c7cb47e4e3c4e ;-)

Comment: That's weird, I copied and pasted it directly into my own document, and then it doesn't work again! :|

Comment: The position of the macro definition is sometimes crucial!

Comment: Already knew that, but it's a direct copy paste, and everything looks the same. It's also not just a single error, but 12 errors. About missing and undefined stuff.

Comment: @Vallentin: Send me a mail (see the address on my profile page) with your current version if possible and I'll take a look

Comment: @Vallentin: I asked you to send me your document, in order to provide an adapted solution that fits your special setup, giving me the chance to have an acceptable answer, but now it's too late

Comment: I really wanted too, but this was a paper for my university. So I really couldn't risk anything. Hope you understand.

Comment: @Vallentin: Well, it's your job to provide a document that is reduced to absolute minimum that still shows the issue. I don't care about the contents of papers at all.